# How to use aggreate functions in Azure Cosmos DB using SQL API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to use aggregate function (SUM) in cosmosdb without success.

I need to calculate the sum of the qty attribute value grouping by SUPPLIER and PARTNUMBERID. I've tried to use the VALUE argument but i receive a sintaxe error message(**"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'VALUE'**), when i don't use VALUE argument, i receive another error message (**"Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE ' for aggregates."**)

My question is what is the correct syntax for this query?

Queries:

```
SELECT   od.SUPPLIER
        ,p.PARTNUMBERID
        ,VALUE SUM(p.QTY) AS QTY
FROM    od
JOIN    p IN od.PARTNUMBER
GROUP   BY od.SUPPLIER, p.PARTNUMBERID

SELECT   od.SUPPLIER
        ,p.PARTNUMBERID
        ,SUM(p.QTY) AS QTY
FROM    od
JOIN    p IN od.PARTNUMBER
GROUP   BY od.SUPPLIER, p.PARTNUMBERID
```

My document structure:

```
[
    {
    "DOCUMENTDATE": "2021-07-20T00:00:00",
    "DOCID": "DOC001",
    "CUSTOMER": "ABCDEF",
    "SUPPLIER": "XPTO",
    "PARTNUMBER": [
        {
            "PARTNUMBERID": "PARTNUMBER0001",
            "QTY": 530,
            "QTYSENT": 74816.306
        },
        {
            "PARTNUMBERID": "PARTNUMBER0002",
            "QTY": 593,
            "QTYSENT": 76432
        }]
    },
    {
    "DOCUMENTDATE": "2021-07-20T00:00:00",
    "DOCID": "DOC002",
    "CUSTOMER": "ABCDEF",
    "SUPPLIER": "ZZZZ",
    "PARTNUMBER": [
        {
            "PARTNUMBERID": "PNZZZZ0001",
            "QTY": 530,
            "QTYSENT": 74816.306
        },
        {
            "PARTNUMBERID": "PNZZZZ0002",
            "QTY": 593,
            "QTYSENT": 76432
        }]
    }
]
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query you're trying to execute. Without looking at the query it would be impossible to say why your query is failing :).

Comment: Seems like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59616403/272109) is very similar and perhaps provides an answer for you. Also, as Gaurav mentioned, there's not much that can be done without being able to see your actual query.

Comment: Thanks David but the query you mentioned doesn't execute a group by

Comment: @JoseMarceloDiasdeOliveira - correct, but it shows how to aggregate items inside an array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With a single partition, your second query worked fine when I tried.

[image]

OR

```
select value total 
from
(
 SELECT   od.SUPPLIER
    ,p.PARTNUMBERID
    ,SUM(p.QTY) AS QTY
 FROM    od
 JOIN    p IN od.PARTNUMBER
 GROUP   BY od.SUPPLIER, p.PARTNUMBERID
) as total
```

[image]

> **Note**: If you have multiple partitions, specify the partition in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot NiharikaMoola. But if the query really needs to access multiple partitions? what can i do?